# What's the difference between client.say and client.send_message?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

The title conveys the question pretty well. What's the difference between client.say and client.send_message? When should I use any of the two over the other?

Comment: It will help if you'll add the version you're using and link to the documentation of these methods.

Comment: Using Python 3.7 and documentation is linked here:
https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [github repo](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/async/discord/ext/commands/bot.py#L321) `say` is literally just `send_message` that gets the destination automatically from the command it was called from.

So `client.say` can only be used within `@client.command()`

```
def say(self, *args, **kwargs):
        """|coro|
        A helper function that is equivalent to doing
        .. code-block:: python
            self.send_message(message.channel, *args, **kwargs)
        The following keyword arguments are "extensions" that augment the
        behaviour of the standard wrapped call.
        Parameters
        ------------
        delete_after: float
            Number of seconds to wait before automatically deleting the
            message.
        See Also
        ---------
        :meth:`Client.send_message`
        """
        destination = _get_variable('_internal_channel')

        extensions = ('delete_after',)
        params = {
            k: kwargs.pop(k, None) for k in extensions
        }

        coro = self.send_message(destination, *args, **kwargs)
        return self._augmented_msg(coro, **params)
```